# How to get the x-axis interval using d3.js?

Tags: d3.js

I have drawn a line chart using d3.js. I need to get the x-axis interval between two x-axis ticks. Is there any way to get this. If yes please let me know how to get the x-axis interval between the ticks.

Comment: Do you want the pixel or userspace interval?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using a quantitative scale, this is as simple as:

```
var numTicks = 5;
var ticks = xScale.ticks(numTicks);
// user space interval
var userSpaceInterval = ticks[1] - ticks[0];
// pixel distance
var pixelInterval = xScale(ticks[1]) - xScale(ticks[0]);
```

Comment: I have tried this and it is giving me the entire ticks and the interval for example : -1000 -800 -600 ... 1000 but i have written code to make the tick count as 5 so in the graph i am getting 1000 500 0 500 1000 so the interval is 500 but i am getting 200 while implementing the above code.. please let me know how to take that..

Comment: @Keshav1007, if you are explicitly specifying a number of ticks, pass that to the `.ticks` call, see above: `xScale.ticks(5);`